# What is the most logical way to store the relationships between wrestlers, their characters, and their entrance music?

Tags: mysql, database-design, properties, entity-relationship, database-schema

### Necessary Background Info

I know the title is specific to my project, so allow me to explain the background of my problem.

I run a website that stores and displays entrance theme listings for various wrestlers, tag teams, pay-per-view shows, and so forth (which I call "Entities"). I am doing a complete refactor, doing mots of the code from scratch, and am reconsidering how I store entrance music listings.

It is possible for each Entity (which would contain one record per human being) to have been in multiple Organizations. For example, the wrestler Kevin Nash (as a person) has been in WWE, WCW, and TNA. Kevin Nash has also had multiple "gimmicks", or characters, sometimes appearing across multiple organizations. For example, Kevin Nash has been known: in WWE as Diesel and by his real name; in TNA as only his real name; and in WCW as Vinnie Vegas, Oz, and his real name.

This is how I most recently decided to store this information:

[image: Entity-Relationship Diagram of my site's Entities and Organizations]

In `entity_types`, I would store the Entity Type of "wrestler" for wrestlers such as Kevin Nash. Kevin Nash would then have an entry in `entities`, which would represent him as a person. Next, Kevin Nash's multiple gimmicks (which, remember, can extend across multiple Organizations) would each be stored in the `entity_gimmicks` table; records would include "Diesel", "Vinnie Vegas", "Oz", and "Kevin Nash" (for when he has appeared as himself, or a characterization of himself).

Within `entity_instances` I would store every instance where one of Kevin Nash's gimmicks has appeared in a particular organization. For example, there would be entries for:

- "Kevin Nash in WWE",
- "Diesel in WWE",
- "Kevin Nash in WCW",
- "Vinnie Vegas in WCW",
- and so forth.

And, of course, `organizations` would store the companies in which a wrestler has appeared.

### The Question at Hand

Now to my question. When a user views a wrestler's theme listing page, I want them to see, e.g., all of Kevin Nash's entrance themes that he used in a particular company (say WWE). This listing would ideally show a listing of *all* themes, for *all* gimmicks used by this person. Let's say Kevin Nash, first as Diesel, used the themes "Abc" and "Def". Then, after leaving the company and returning as Kevin Nash himself, he used the themes "Ghi" and "Jkl". *How could I best sort these theme listings?*

At first glance, one would simply say that the code could retrieve first the gimmicks, then the themes in each gimmick, and order them based on the order of the gimmicks. The problem with this, however, is that it is within the realm of possibility for a wrestler to switch between gimmicks. For example, John Doe could have first been called "The Crusader", then known as John Doe, then back again as "The Crusader", each with new entrance music. If "The Crusader" is one gimmick entry, how would the themes stored under that gimmick mesh with the themes stored under the "John Doe" gimmick?

This is the conundrum I face. I could add an `entity_org_sort_order` column to the `themes` table, but that could potentially be a nightmare when my administrators go to edit a wrestler's theme listing.

Can anybody see a solution that would solve my problem? Even if it means going back to the drawing board to reconsider how I store all of this information, I am willing to consider that.

Comment: I think, you are having way too many tables at the moment. 
1) I could avoid entitiy_types table my keeping type_id in entities as an ENUM.
2) May be, I would consider joining entity_gimmicks and entity_instances. This will be against normalization, but will certainly avoid a JOIN happening in most queries

Comment: I changed it so that a record in `entities` can now have multiple instances within `entity_gimmicks`. Each instance must have an `org_id` connected to the `organizations` table. Thank you for your advice! It's starting to make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late answer on this. I came across it as I search “wrestling”, being a fan, and curious to see if there were any wrestling-related questions on the site!

Your project sounds interesting. I don’t know if you ever solved the problem but I would have looked at your entities and split them into your own table. So you mention *people*, *gimmicks*, *organisations*, and *entrance themes*. Your relationships would then look like this:

- A person has many gimmicks.
- A gimmick has a many-to-many relationship with organisations (as like you say, Kevin Nash wrestled under his real name in WWE, WCW, and TNA).

With these two relationships, you could then find what gimmicks Kevin Nash used in WWE, or for which organisations he wrestled under his real name.

Entrance themes gets complicated. Do you want to associate a theme with a person or a gimmick? I’d personally associate a theme with a gimmick, and usually a gimmick change sees a wrestler adopt a new piece of music. I can’t really think of any gimmick changes where a wrestler’s used the same theme across it. So now you have:

- A gimmick has many entrance themes

Using Laravel, these relations would yield the following tables:

- `people`
- `gimmicks` (foreign key to `person`)
- `organisations`
- `entrance_themes` (foreign key to `gimmick`)
- `gimmick_organisation` (pivot table)

You can then find what themes a wrestler has used in an organisation by listing their gimmicks for that organisation, and then the entrance themes for that subset of gimmicks.

Comment: I'm revisiting this concept, and your answer has perfect timing. Yes, `themes` should belong to `gimmicks` and not `people`.

Comment: @TerranRich Glad to have helped! What is the project, out of interest?

Comment: An updated version of "Xylot Themes", a website devoted to keeping track of which themes a wrestler has used. You can view the current version at: http://xylotthemes.com/